# MySQL - Help me construct this query

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I have a relational DB that I can't think of how to form this query.

Here's the info

Table1

```
id name
1  Mike
```

Table2

```
id table_1_id value      setting
1  1          something  setting1
2  1          something2  setting2
2  1          something3  setting3
```

Currently, this is my sql query

```
SELECT *  FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 on Table2.table_1_id = Table1.id
```

What this outputs is something like this

```
id name table_1_id value      setting
1  Mike 1          something1 setting1
1  Mike 1          something2 setting2
1  Mike 1          something3 setting3
```

Is it possible to construct this in such a way to return these results so I can export it to a CSV file?

```
id name table_1_id something1 something2 something3
1  Mike 1          setting1   setting2   setting3
```

Comment: Sure. Use `SELECT (tablename).(columnname)`, separating each with commas as necessary. If you want to _alias_ a column (i.e. change its name in your resultset) use `SELECT (tablename).(columnname) AS (newname)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Table1.*,
    something1Table.setting AS something1,
    something2Table.setting AS something2,
    something3Table.setting AS something3
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 AS something1Table ON something1Table.table_1_id = Table1.id AND something1Table.value = 'something'
JOIN Table2 AS something2Table ON something2Table.table_1_id = Table1.id AND something2Table.value = 'something2'
JOIN Table2 AS something3Table ON something3Table.table_1_id = Table1.id AND something3Table.value = 'something3'
```

Comment: i would like to see demo if there is

Comment: What if there are 10 entries for table_id = 1. Will join the table 10 times?

Comment: You want to select columns with ten different names then, so yes.

Comment: Trying to see if this one will work on sqlfiddle to compare results/performance and cannot get it to work http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1fdf/3

Comment: I didn't know of sqlfiddle, have looked at your entry and fixed the syntax: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1fdf/9 I'll correct the answer, too.

Comment: @OrganizedChaos here is a demo showing the multiple joins working -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1fdf/13

Comment: flup - thanks for the answer and adjusting the sqlfiddle (I don't know about it either until I saw bluefeet's example).  Both examples appear to be about as efficient as each other and both are correct IMO.  Thank you.

Comment: There is one difference between both solutions, namely what happens if more than one setting is provided for a value. This lot-of-joins solution will provide all selected settings, in multiple rows. The aggregate select will keep providing one single row. I'd imagine the preferred situation depends on your use case.

Comment: I ended up using this solution and it worked perfectly after looking at the sqlfiddle.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need a conditional aggregation:

```
select table1.id, table1.name,
       max(case when value = 'something1' then setting end) as setting1,
       max(case when value = 'something2' then setting end) as setting2,
       max(case when value = 'something3' then setting end) as setting3
from table1 join
     table2
     on table1.id = table2.id
group by table1.id, table1.name
```

Answer (score 1):

This type of data transformation is known an a *pivot* but MySQL does not have a pivot function. So you will want to replicate it using an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression.

If you know the the number of values ahead of time, then you can hard-code your query similar to this:

```
select t1.id, 
  t1.name,
  max(case when t2.value = 'something' then t2.setting end) as setting1,
  max(case when t2.value = 'something2' then t2.setting end) as setting2,
  max(case when t2.value = 'something3' then t2.setting end) as setting3
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
  on t1.id = t2.table_1_id
group by t1.id, t1.name;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8633/6)

But if you have an unknown number of values that you want to transform into columns, then you can use a [prepared statement to generate dynamic sql](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html).

The query would be similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'max(case when t2.value = ''',
      value,
      ''' then t2.setting end) AS `',
      value, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM  table2;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT t1.id, 
                    t1.name, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM table1 t1
                  left join table2 t2
                    on t1.id = t2.table_1_id
                  group by t1.id, t1.name');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8633/7)

The result of both versions is:

```
| ID | NAME | SOMETHING | SOMETHING2 | SOMETHING3 |
---------------------------------------------------
|  1 | Mike |  setting1 |   setting2 |   setting3 |
```

Comment: Awesome info, the first part of this looks like what I was looking for, thanks for taking the time to create the sqlfiddle.  I modified it a little (to add other values in the db) and it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @OrganizedChaos happy to help, I am glad it is working for you. :)

Comment: While I think both this and flup's answers can be correct, I marked this one for the extra detail and alternative solution.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP_CONCAT may be of use. It doesn't give you exactly what you want, because it would put the concatenated values into a single field. But depending on what you're actually trying to accomplish, perhaps you can work around that. The advantage of the GROUP_CONCAT is that it can handle any number of table2 rows per table1 row, whereas the conditional aggregation above hardwires having three entries (which may well be what you want).

```
SELECT table1.*, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(value) AS value_group,
    GROUP_CONCAT(setting) AS setting_group 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.table_1_id = table1.id
```

returns

```
id,person,value_group,setting_group
1,Mike,"something1,something2,something3","setting1,setting2,setting3"
```